# Accessing javascript from watch window in visual studio?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, debugging, visual-studio-express, watch-window

I'm missing the ability to do 'document.getElementbyId('foo')' and evaluate it or get a list of all the methods etc. when setting a break point in the code behind.

Is this possible to get it from the watch window? (when I type 'document' in the watch window it says:"The name 'document' does not exist in the current context")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading Simon Wang's comment, an idea came into my mind:

In the .aspx file I write:

```
<asp:Literal Text="" ID="activate_debugger" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
```

In the code-behind, instead of setting a break point, before the line I would usually create a breakpoing I write:

```
activate_debugger.Text = "<script type='text/javascript'>debugger;</script>";
```

now I can open the watch window and write document.getElementById('foo');

Answer (score 1):

If you want to just watch javasript, I suggest FireBug plugin in firefox, or Google Chrome Developer Tool bug(F12), or IE developer tool bar(F12)

Comment: (I find firebug and friends lacking comparing to quickwatch in readability and functionality for example evaluating a div.innerhtml after I reach a break point in the c# code). Anyway thank you for helping me focus my question.